# Error occured when I, build CoRE4INET with inet 3.8.3 in OMNeT++ 6.0.2

Tags: makefile

Error occured when I, build CoRE4INET with  inet 3.8.3  in OMNeT++ 6.0.2
I received error message: cannot find inet framework in the usual location.you have to set the path to inet in inet_proj variable. However, I put both CoRE4INET and inet in the same location(workspace: sample).
please can anyone help me!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.